# Does a JavaScript Anonymous function have access to other parameters passed along with it?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a function that takes 2 parameters, a regular variable and a function.

```
function example(varA, function(){
  //do something with varA?
})
```

Can I use varA in the definition of the anonymous function? If I run this function and pass in something for varA, does the anonymous function know what the vale of varA is?

Comment: This is invalid syntax. You must specify identifiers as parameters. Since the function you pass in when calling as `example(1, passedFunc)` is by definition external, no, you cannot access `varA` from within that function, since `varA` is local to `example`.

Comment: function definition should have a function callback variable and not function definition. `function example(varA, callback){}` and you will have to pass necessary variables to callback

Answer (score 0):

Answer is NO!

Your definition is incorrect.

```
function example(varA, function(){
  //do something with varA?
});
```

During function definition, you do not know what the callback would look like and so it should be:

```
function example(varA, callback){}
```

Now in following example:

```js
function test(varA){
  function notify(){
    console.log(varA);
  }
  notify();
}

test(10)
```

`varA` is accessible because it is in same scope, but if you do something like this:

```js
function test(varA, callback){
  callback();
}

test(10, function(){
  
  // This will throw error, because there is no variable called varA
  console.log(varA);
})
```

and you will have to pass arguments to callback.

```js
function test(varA, callback){
  callback(varA);
}

test(10, function(varA){
  console.log(varA);
})
```